# Como adicionar um grafico do Matplotlib no tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib

Tenho um grafico do matplotlib porem em formato (pizza) e queria pegar a figura do grafico e adiciona-lo ao tkinter
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

```
DataBaser.cursor.execute("""
SELECT RendaMensal FROM Registro
Where Status = 'On'
""")

RendaGet = DataBaser.cursor.fetchone()

Renda = RendaGet[0]

print(Renda)

DataBaser.cursor.execute("""
SELECT TotalDebt FROM Registro
Where Status = 'On'
""")

TotalDebt = DataBaser.cursor.fetchone()

Debt = TotalDebt[0]

print(Debt)

sizes = [Debt, Renda]

labels = 'Gastos', 'Renda'

fig1, axl = plt.subplots()

colors = ['red', 'green']

c2 = axl.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%0.0f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90, colors=colors)

axl.axis('equal')

circle = axl.axis('equal')

#plt.xticks(Renda)


plt.title("Controle do Limite")
plt.show()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(c2, DataFrame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
#canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estou criando 2 figuras, fig1, na qual voce usa para plotar o grafico estilo pizza (pie chart)  e  f na qual voce usa para cirar o FigureCanvasTkAgg. Removendo o f e usando o fig1 no FigureCanvasTkAgg

Algo Como:

```
fig1, axl = plt.subplots()
c2 = axl.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%0.0f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90,  colors=colors)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=DataFrame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)
Respondido no StackOverflow(USA) por: **Diziet Asahi**
```